# Cancellation for Field Extensions

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory, extension-field

Suppose $K,L$ are number fields with coprime discriminants. Let $N/\mathbb{Q}$ be the galois closure of $K/\mathbb{Q}$. Is it true that 
$$[NL:KL] = [N:K] $$
I feel that this would be true, with some argument having to do with the discriminants being coprime but I cant quite get it.

Edit: I know that $\gcd(D_N, D_L) = 1$.

Comment: We want to show $[NL:\mathbb{Q}]=[N:K][KL:\mathbb{Q}]$. But it’s well-known that $[K \cap L:\mathbb{Q}][KL:\mathbb{Q}]=[L:\mathbb{Q}][K:\mathbb{Q}]$, and similarly replacing $K$ with $N$. The condition becomes equivalent to $[N\cap L:\mathbb{Q}]=[K \cap L:\mathbb{Q}]$ ie $N \cap L = K \cap L$. But $K \cap L$, $N \cap L$ are number fields with discriminants dividing $(D_K,D_L)=1$, and $(D_N,D_L)=1$ as well (I think...) so by Minkowski’s theorem they are $\mathbb{Q}$ and we are done.

Answer (score 0):

By basic field theory we have $[NL:KL]$ = $[N:N\cap KL]$, so we need to show that $K = N\cap KL$. $N\cap KL\supseteq K$ is trivial, so it suffices to show that $N\cap L\subseteq K$. In fact we can show that under your hypotheses, $N\cap L =\mathbb{Q}$.

Indeed, a prime ramifies in $N$ iff it ramifies in $K$ iff it divides $D_K$, and similarly a prime ramifies in $D_L$ iff it divides $D_L$. Since $(D_L,D_K)=1$ by assumption, the sets of primes ramifying in these fields are disjoint. Now suppose some prime $p$ ramifies in $N \cap L$. Then $p$ must ramify in both $N$ and $L$, but this is impossible by what we've shown.

Thus $K\cap L$ is an unramified extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, which must be trivial since the (narrow) class group of $\mathbb{Q}$ is $1$. Alternatively for a proof not using class field theory, as in Mindlack's comment you can use Minkowski's theorem to show that any extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ has non-trivial discriminant and hence some prime ramifies, giving the necessary contradiction.